# Adding a library file into a binary file

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, ldd

I have compiled a source code and included proper library files in the LDFLAGS. However, as I want to run the binary, it says a specific libX.a is missing. If I add the library's path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, everything will be OK.

Is there any way to permanently include that file in the binary in order to eliminate the LD_LIBRARY_PATH step?

```
LDFLAGS=-L/export/apps/computer/scalapack -L/export/apps/computer/OpenBLAS-0.2.18
BLAS_LIBS=-lopenblas
SCALAPACK_LIBS=-lscalapack

COMP_LIBS=dc_lapack.a liblapack.a libblas.a
LIBS=$(SCALAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS)
```

The output of `ldd` command, shows

```
# ./siesta
./siesta: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# ldd siesta
    libopenblas.so.0 => not found
    ...
```

However,

```
# ls ../../../computer/OpenBLAS-0.2.18/libopenblas* -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       33 Jul 27 11:58 ../../../computer/OpenBLAS-0.2.18/libopenblas.a -> libopenblas_piledriverp-r0.2.18.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28091912 Jul 27 11:59 ../../../computer/OpenBLAS-0.2.18/libopenblas_piledriverp-r0.2.18.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14912094 Jul 27 12:00 ../../../computer/OpenBLAS-0.2.18/libopenblas_piledriverp-r0.2.18.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       34 Jul 27 12:00 ../../../computer/OpenBLAS-0.2.18/libopenblas.so -> libopenblas_piledriverp-r0.2.18.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       34 Jul 27 12:00 ../../../computer/OpenBLAS-0.2.18/libopenblas.so.0 -> libopenblas_piledriverp-r0.2.18.so
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have three possibilities

1. Link the siesta program static.

or i guess you are looking for:

2. Install OpenBLAS libraries in a path, that is already in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH like /usr/local/lib
3. Use -Wl,-R/path/to/OpenBLAS compiler flag

Comment: Can you explain about the first method

Comment: replace -shared with -static in the Makefile or instead of -lopenblas write the fullpath to the openblas static library to the object fileslist